# New to JavaScript, difficulty understanding passing a parameter

Tags: javascript

In the following code I know adding () at the end of the Function makes it a self invoking function.

However I don't understand if passing "socialMedia" which is an object is being passed as a parameter or for some other reason.

```
var social = function(){

}(socialMedia);
```

Comment: because it is than available as an argument to the method and you can reference it. Most libraries will do this so you can alias the varaible and not have to reference the original name.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: If its being passed to a function, *by definition* its a parameter.

Comment: You seem to understand that its calling the function with a single argument `socialMedia`.  So, what difficulty are you having?

Comment: @SumitMaingi w3schools is terrible, use something else.

Comment: I agree with @ASDFGerte - [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/) provides way better information and gets updated regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function by passing the value. Have a look at the below code:

```
var add = function(val){alert(val)}(100);
```

This would trigger the `add` function with val assigned to `100`.